# How to Create a New Dataframe From Old Dataframe Based on Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, postgresql-9.2

I have a situation at work where I need to create a new Dataframe from a previous one

The previous dataframe looks like:
|id|name|balance|deleted|minimum_balance|payment_provider_account_id|type|api_user_id|customer_id|
|-----|------------|------:|------:|--------------:|---------------------------|--------|-|-|
|38049|LIDIA CIUBUC|3.58   |-1     |2.0            |lidia.ciubuc                      |PERSONAL|NaN|38049|

The new dataframe will have the same columns, but I need to:
Check if the name of every single row on previous dataframe already exists on new dataframe
If it the name does not exist, I add the row on new dataframe
If it exists, I need to check if deleted status on previous one is -1
If is not -1, I need to sum the balance of previous dataframe on new datafarme
If is -1, I need to temporary store the existing balance on new dataframe, replace the row by the one from previous dataframe, and them sum the temporary balance on the replaced row on new dataframe.

My code so far is:

```
import sys, psycopg2
import pandas as pd

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="<db_IP>",port=<DB_port>,dbname="dbname",user="postgres",password="Start123")
cur = conn.cursor()
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM money_account;',conn)

cur.rowcount
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()

dc = 1
rc = 0
print(df.loc[0])
rows = df.loc[dc-1]
print(rows)
type(rows)

for x in rows.id:
    for y in df.id:
        if rows.name[rc] == df.names[dc]:
            if df.deleted[dc] != -1:
                rows.balance[rc] = rows.balance[rc] + df.balance[dc]
            else:
                temp = rows.balance[rc]
                rows[rc] = df[dc]
                rows.balance[rc] = rows.balance[rc] + temp
        else:
            dc = dc +1
    rc = rc + 1
print(rows)
```

But I am receiving the following error:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-316da58d0cb6> in <module>
      6 type(rows)
      7 
----> 8 for x in rows.id:
      9     for y in df.id:
     10         if rows.name[rc] == df.balance[dc]:

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you show us the code efforts you have made to solve this problem and the exact problem you encounter? The StackOverflow community rarely provides tailored code solutions ;) You'll have more luck getting an answer if there's an specific answerable technical issue in the question.

Comment: I did some updates on my code. So far, it seems is working now. It's no complete, I still need to write the code to send to database the content of the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following code worked for me:

```
import sys, psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import csv

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="127.0.0.1",port=5433,dbname="YPSDB",user="postgres",password="Start123")
cur = conn.cursor()
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM money_account;',conn)


cur.rowcount
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
df_list = df.values.tolist()
df_items=list(df)

for indout in range(len(df_list)-1):
    if df_list[indout][6] == 'PERSONAL':
        if df_list[indout][3] == -1:
            for indin in range(len(df_list)-1):
                if df_list[indout][5] == df_list[indin][5]:
                    if df_list[indin][3] != -1 & bool(df_list[indin][2] != 0.0):
                        df_list[indout][2] = round(df_list[indout][2] + df_list[indin][2],2)

lista = [sub for sub in df_list if -1 in sub]

with open('final balance.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
      
    write.writerow(df_items)
    write.writerows(lista)
```

Of course, I am open to suggestions to improve it